# Qt C++ customized slot does not work

Tags: qt, connect, slot

I am trying to connect a button with a slot defined in an external class called `simu`. The slot is a function called `startSimu()`. The object `simulation` is instantiated in the same class where I hope to connect the button. Below is the code:

```
QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton("start simulation");
simu simulation;
QObject::connect(btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &simulation, SLOT(startSimu()));
```

The code compiles and runs, but when I click on the button nothing happens. The function `startSimu()` is the following:

```
void simu::startSimu() {
    std::cout << "aaaa" << std::endl;
}
```

The header of the `simu` class:

```
#ifndef SIMU_H
#define SIMU_H

#include <QObject>

class simu : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    simu();
    double timer() {return time;}

public slots:
    void startSimu();


private:
    double time;
};

#endif // SIMU_H
```

I hope someone has a clue or a hint!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `simulation` object destroyed before the slot is called, because you allocated it in the stack:

```
simu simulation; // Will be destroyed as the execution leave the scope.
QObject::connect(btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &simulation, SLOT(startSimu()));
```

To fix this you will need probably do the following:

```
simu *simulation = new simu; // Will be destroyed soon
QObject::connect(btn1, SIGNAL(clicked()), simulation, SLOT(startSimu()));
```

Please do not forget to delete the `simulation` object when needed.

Comment: The last thing to add is, don't forget to delete it.

Comment: Also we had trouble with cout in some configurations, you could try raising an QMessageBox during development or use qDebug()/qWarning() with a custom message handler